# Excel Macro: Pasting Values from Sheet into a Table Error

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I am trying to copy data from worksheet "Project Summary Data" and paste it into a table on worksheet "Project Cost Report Summary". I am very new to Macro's, so I am unsure of what I am doing wrong here, but the error seems to be around this part `tbl.Range("D7").Paste`.

I need to paste the data into Cell "D7" on the "Project Cost Report Summary" which would technically be the first row of data in the table (no headers), and the 4th column of the table.

error I am receiving is Run-Time error '1004': Unable to get the select property of the range class

```vba
Sub filter_copy_paste()

Dim region As String
Dim Report As Worksheet
Dim Data As Worksheet
Dim count_col As Integer
Dim count_row As Integer
Dim tbl As ListObject


Set Report = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project Cost Report Summary")
Set Data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project Summary Data")
region = Data.Range("I1").Text
Set tbl = Report.ListObjects("Table2")

'determine the size of the range
Data.Activate
count_col = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight)))
count_row = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)))

'filter data on Raw Data tab
Data.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=region

'Copy and Paste to Cost Report

Data.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(count_row, count_col)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
tbl.Range("D7").Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Show Data and Remove the Filter
With Data
.ShowAllData
.AutoFilterMode = False

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! What error is shown? Please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1833022/edit) your question and add that information.

Comment: I believe you did identify the issue. Since tbl is a listobject you probably want something like `.DataBodyRange(1, 4)`.

Comment: unrelated instead of one line for copy and the second line for paste, you should be able, in one line, set the databodyrange to be equal to that of the `.value` you are copying. Happy coding!